# Unhandled promise rejection error while testing with jasmine

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request, jasmine

The server is working (tested with postman). The code also works if I start the server and I delete the beforeAll and afterAll handlers. The console output is:
App listening on port 3200!
after server start
I don't understand where is the problem.

```
import request from 'request';
import { start, stop } from '../src/server';



describe('A suite', function () {

  beforeAll(async () => {
    await start();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await stop();
  });

  it('server test', async () => {
    const data = { tableName: 'supply' };

    console.log('after server start');

    const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request.post({
        url: 'http://localhost:3200/getTable',
        json: data
      }, (error, response, body) => {
        if (error) {
          reject(body);
        } else {
          resolve(body);
        }
      });
    });

    console.log(response);
  });
});
```

```
const start = async (): Promise<void> => {
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    server = app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`App listening on port ${port}!`);
      resolve();
    });
  });
}

const stop = async (): Promise<void> => {
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => server.close(() => {
    console.log('App closed successfully')
    resolve();
  }));
}
```

I found out that the problem is that when I run the tests the connection to the database cannot be made. Any idea how can I create a connection to the database when I run jasmine? What's the difference between calling start() from the test or just running npm start. When I use npm start everything works fine but when I call it from jasmine the connection to db cannot be made.

It's a typescript problem, something like the tests are run with node, but they should run with ts-node. I run the test with the commands: tsc; jasmine.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using **jasmine-ts**. the problem was that I ran my tests with **tsc; jasmine**